# How can I dynamically build Functions in javascript

Tags: javascript

Firstly, I am new to javascript.
I am trying to build a webpage to keep track of some numbers for a game.
The game involves keeping track of statistics for a character, in two sections. 1) Base Statistics (Strength, Dexterity ...) and 2) Skills (Drive car, sword, electronics repair, painting ...)
I have a PHP script to call the Stats, with input boxes to adjust them, and a JavaScript code to add them up as they are altered. This works fine for the 8 Stats, but I have written a separate function for each (getStrength, getDexterity ...), with a getTotal function that sums them and displays.

I would like to use a similar process for the 150 Skills (~10 categories with ~15 skills each), without writing 150 separate functions (getDrive, get sword, get painting ...)
I can pull the Skill List from database. Can I run a loop over this to create the required functions?

Comment: It is possible to create functions within a loop; what it would take in your case would depend on knowing what your code is.

Comment: DON'T. Use arrays and object as containers and write a general .get() function that you pass an object and a name of a property or an index. That way you only need 1 function to work on everything instead of 1 fucntion for every seperate piece.

Comment: I don't even think you need a loop.  It sounds like you just need to pass your categories and skills as parameters in on e function.  The place your logic within the one function.

Comment: wow thanks for quick replies!
I am currently basing code on this example:  http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-calculator-script.phtml

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would code such things. There's downsides to this approach as well (it doesn't minify well and such), but at least you don't have to define 200 functions that all do the same thing: return a property of your character:

```
var Charcter = function Character( name ) {
    this.id = {
        'name' : name,
        'class' : 'ranger',
        'level' : 1
    }
    this.stats = {
        'str' : 10,
        'dex' : 18,
        'con' : 14,
        'int' : 10,
        'wis' : 16,
        'cha' : 16
    };
    this.skills = [
        'archery',
        'horsemanship'
    ];
};
Character.prototype = {
    'get' : function get( subType, fieldName ) {
        return this[subType][fieldName];
    }
};

var shilly = new Character('shilly');

console.log('I am a ' + shilly.get('id', 'class') + ' of level ' + shilly.get('id', 'level') );
console.log('My second skill is ' + shilly.get('skills', 1) + '.' );
```

Comment: Ah, I think I see how to use that (although I still have to write ALL this skills in character definition, and recall, as I need to sum the total of all skills (actually with a multiplier by category).